# ExtJs MultiSelect Windows 8 Chrome clicking on vertical scroll arrow buttons resets the selection

Tags: extjs, windows-8, scrollbar, multi-select

I am facing a strange issue in my ExtJs 6.0.1 Classic application, which we are developing for both Desktop (Windows 7, Windows 8) and iPad platforms.

We are using multiselect field in several places and it works perfectly on Windows 7 and iPad platforms where we can select multiple items using mouse clicks on desktop machines and using touch on iPad. On Windows 8  (Surface Pro) machine also we are able to select multiple items using touch, however, if we click / touch on Top or Bottom arrow on scroll-bar of multiselect field, the selected values disappears and entire selection is automatically reset.

This issue occurs only on Windows 8 machine and only if we click/touch on the Top / Bottom arrow on multiselect scrollbar. If we scroll through the list using Touch, the selection persist.

Comment: Please try to reproduce in a fiddle, and if you have it, make a bug report from it over at Sencha Forum.

Comment: Are you able to add breakpoint/listener to the field's change/reset events to let you trace it back to what's triggering it?

Comment: @Alexander - Yes, I will do that. Thanks

Comment: @Stuart - Yes, I did, but no luck. Not sure what is triggering the reset.